# Android WebView zoom image not working for width="100%"

Tags: android, zooming, android-webview

When I use the following html:

```
img src="file:///sdcard/image1.jpg" width="100%" heighth="100%"
```

and use `WebView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)`, my webview is zoomable, but after I release my finger, the webview is zoomed back.

I guess it is because of `width="100%" heighth="100%"`.

But `image1.jpg` is big, and at the beginning I want to show the whole image on screen.  Later the user can zoom in/out.

Any solution  or code sample?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the scale that you need to use manually. PIC_WIDTH is the width of the webview.

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); 
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(PIC_WIDTH);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

Then use

```
WebView web = new WebView(this);
web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
web.setInitialScale(getScale());
```

Refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen)  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923610/fit-image-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're writing it wrong!

```
img src="file:///sdcard/image1.jpg" width="100%" heighth="100%"
img src="file:///sdcard/image1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"
```

It is height and not what you've got there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only showing a image off the Sd card are you sure you want to use a webview, or would it make more sense to use a ImageView. There are lots of examples/free code that Extend ImageView and provide this functionality.

A Webview may be the most bloated way of handling this functionality if all you want to do is display an image.

Comment: yes.but i'm drawing on image in webview and thats too much lighter and fast than imageview