# display image with WebView in android

Tags: android, webview

i'm try to display url (content is only one image) in webview but webview display image larger than this real dimention .

how i fit image in webView ?

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594793/2233621