# Setting webview at the center of relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am setting following property for webview

```
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and using following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/solid_white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" android:gravity="center">


     <WebView
        android:id="@+id/MyView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </WebView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is for fragment. View is coming centrally vertical but it not coming centrally horizontal.
What I need to do to set webview at the center of relative layout?

Comment: Your code is showing perfectly in Center.

Comment: @jeet It is wokring But I want whatever size of webview it should take that much any other solution any other option.

Comment: Hey try this property in your webview.
`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

perhaps it will work for you.

Comment: @RobinHood there is no such property for webview or relative layout.

Comment: Check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142699/need-help-in-displaying-image-correctly-in-webview-in-android

Comment: @Vivek did u solve the above problem,, please let me know the solution.

Comment: @Adi Yes I have resolved the problem I will add answer shortly

Comment: @Vivek Please add the solution as soon as possible as I'm stuck with it.. you can mail me too @  adithya.am1989@gmail.com . awaiting your response

Answer (score 4):

Just try this:

```
MyView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
MyView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Actually Android WebView's wrap content layout paramter fill the parent width, and I believe its coz it is being optimized to use all the screen width, so you need to set some fixed width, to show in center

Comment: is this the same issue you are referring to?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655827/webview-orientation-change-issue/18656844?noredirect=1#18656844

Answer (score 1):

In Relative Layout attribute change like this :

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

No need to add **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** in WebView Hope it will work.

Comment: As there is only one view WebView inaide RelativeLayout so there may be problem.can you post the image please.what your are getting till now if you dont mind.