# How to stop android webview from wrapping content while zooming?

Tags: android, android-webview

Android webview auto wraps content while zoom in and out. For example, while zooming in, it wraps one line of text to next line, and therefore the layout is changed. But what I want to achieve is only zooming in without changing any layout. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938464/setting-webview-at-the-center-of-relative-layout) finally.

```
MyView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
MyView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Hi. I have further the prevent content reflow. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357787/how-to-stop-android-webview-content-reflow-when-double-tapped/14374230#14374230)