# How to stop android webview content reflow when double tapped?

Tags: android, zooming, android-webview, reflow

First of all, I would like the WebView can be scrolled but it need to behave just like a picture such that the scrolling would not cause the WebView to rearrange its layout to fit screen. It should just provide scrollbar when the page is really bigger than screen.

I have read [How to stop android webview from wrapping content while zooming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103402/how-to-stop-android-webview-from-wrapping-content-while-zooming). It works except the double tap performed.

To regenerate the problem, 
1. I load a  web page which is full of text to fullscreen WebView.
2. double tap the right side of screen. <--here it just zoom in, no problem
3. double tap the left side of screen.

The problem come. The text is rearranged. When I zoom back to original scale. The text is just fill in half of the screen.

How to stop webView to rearrange its layout no matter what is happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally solve of this by this line.

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

By default, the `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm` is `NARROW_COLUMNS`.

By study the `android.webkit.ZoomManager` class, it must reflow (rearrange) if `NARROW_COLUMNS` and the else case is reflow if necessary. I don't know what the "necessary" is but as least it won't reflow anymore in my case.

There is some off-topic but my goal is to prevent content reflow. I found out that on Android 2.x device, sometime, the web page content would reflow if I click the zoomControl button even though set `webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`.On Android 4, this problem is not exist.

If I am not mistaken. I think it is the web page meta tag cause this. Therefore, I make sure the web page don't have this line:`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` .And I really can see the different that without this line, the web content do not reflow.