# WebView doesnt wrap text correctly (pictures inside)

Tags: android, webview, word-wrap, android-websettings

I am having trouble with webview wrapping my html incorrectly.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.loadUrl(getArguments().getString(URL));
```

Ive set a border around body to see it, but webview leaves weird margin on the right, as if the text was scaled first and then the border was drawn, i dont know .. *The stock browser however wraps it just fine*

[image]
[image]

I am not a web developer som please bear with me. I just presume its a webview issue as the stock browser renders it just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Set width and height to match_parent

Comment: Doesnt help .. What I noticed is when rotated to landscape, the text is closer to the border. To me it looks like the text is wrapped and then the page is zoomed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webview reflows text by default, so to not reflow it, set algorithm to

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

as in [How to stop android webview content reflow when double tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357787/how-to-stop-android-webview-content-reflow-when-double-tapped)