# Load Youtube video in WebView

Tags: android

I want to load the youtube video in Web-view, that opens after login page in web-view.

Is it possible to  load inner Youtube video in Web-view?

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
webView.loadUrl("");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.clearCache(false);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

webView.setWebViewClient(new MyOwnWebViewClient());
class MyOwnWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156411/loading-youtube-video-through-i-frame-in-android-webview) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475707/youtube-video-in-webview-doesnt-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475707/youtube-video-in-webview-doesnt-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this it worked for me in inner Youtube video of youtube.

```
if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } else if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of things i did when i was working on one the similar kind of project. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655827/webview-orientation-change-issue) to my question which has the code and other things i did.