# Android:How to display Full-Size Image In Webview.

Tags: android, image, webview, gallery

Does anyone know if there's a means to have a webview open with an image completely visible (full-size) initially?  The images in question are larger than the screen resolution so they would be scaled with a bar where the scales don't match.  When I set:

```
    zoomView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    zoomView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    zoomView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I get the image zoomed to the max width, leaving some scrolling necessary at max zoom (can't see the whole image).

Ideally I'd love to just use the built-in Honeycomb gallery3d functionality, but unfortunately I can't find the source to see how they pull that off.

Answer (score 0):

**Try setting** Webview's `LayoutAlgorithm` to `SINGLE_COLUMN`. This will resize only those images with Width greater than the width of the device. This won't help you with images smaller than the screen.

`webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);`

Link: [Can Android's WebView automatically resize huge images?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327010/1533054)

Comment: SINGLE_COLUMN is deprecated, and if used hyperlinks do not work.

Comment: SINGLE_COLUMN might be deprecated, but it's the only way without using CSS. BTW I checked it out, and Hyperlinks are working fine. Tested on Nexus 7 (4.1) and Galaxy Nexus (4.0, 4.1, 4.2).

Comment: Some links work, some don't, maybe it's dependent on complexity of HTML, maybe dependent on Android version. But that's proven. Don't be surprised when your customers start to complain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setUseWideViewPort - it loads the WebView completely zoomed out.
You just have to edit max-width of elements in your HTML