# Howto size an image in a webview correctly

Tags: android, webview

I have:

- A Dialog with an webview in it. The dialog can have different sizes on the screen.
- I have a html in the webview with an image tag and size properties.

What I want:

- I would like to have the picture with a size of 1 cm (Centimeter) square.
  How can I achieve this ? I realized that the size of width and height of the image tag is not equal to pixels in my case. If I set the width of the image to the screensize, then the picture is displayed much larger then the screenwidth.

Code:
Cm in Pixel:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    fDensityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
    float pixelperinch = getfDensityDpi();
    float inchpercm = 1.0f / 2.54f;
    pixelPerCm = (int) (inchpercm * pixelperinch + 0.5);
```

Content for the webview:

```
 "<img width=\"" + pixelPerCm + "\" height=\"" + pixelPerCm + "\"  src=\"" + imagePath + "\" " + sStyle + ">"
```

The size of the picture on the device is not the expecting 1 cm.

Can someone help me howto size in Image in a webview to exactly one cm on every device ?

Comment: I finally found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7822858/1344545

Answer (score 0):

you need to set fix height and width of image in webpage.

1 cm  = 38px almost

you can use 38px for 1cm.

Comment: Thats wrong. Every device has a different density, so 38px is different on every device regarding physical size.

Answer (score 0):

For webview you can use dpTopx method

```
   public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public static int pxToDp(int px) {
        return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

Comment: My question is not howto get the size, but howto apply the size to html in a webview. You can see, that I have already the correct size.