# Android How to using webview display full size in huge image

Tags: android, image, webview

I have huge-image , but i can't using webview to display full size in tablet .
Only display a part , it cannot display full image

how can i do ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the Image you're loading in to the `Webview` overflows the device width, you can try changing the Webview's `LayoutAlgorithm` to Single Column.

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

This automatically adjusts image size for all screen sizes and orientations.

Via [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327010/1533054) Question