# Android - adding a image in html webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Ok so the image i'm using is called test.png and I have a java class (Cherry.java) and a xml class (cherry.xml)  Also I have a html file in the /res/raw folder called htmltest.html.  What i'm trying to do is when the user clicks a button on the previous page and then takes them to cherry.xml all it is a webview.  Now in the java class its just opening up the htmltest file and in the html file is just a normal web based layout.  I want to display images in the html file so a image thats in the drawable folder or something like that with out having to use the internet.  (don't want the internet permission to be used).  Below is the code for the 3 files I have.

cherry.xml

```
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webviewHelp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />
```

Cherry.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Cherry extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cherry);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);
        webview.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.htmltest), "text/html", "utf-8");   

    }

    private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID)
    {
        InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;
        try
        {
            i = raw.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            stream.write(i);
            i = raw.read();
        }
        raw.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return stream.toString();
    }



}
```

htmltest.html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<h2>Pictures</h2>
<img border="0" src="file:///android_drawable/test.png" alt="nothing" width="304" height="228" />

</body>
</html>
```

Any more questions just ask and i'll reply as fast as possible.
Everything works fine its just the images that I can't get to display.

Comment: Android 2.2 API 8 - is what this is running

Comment: plz make sure your image and html file in the same folder, If the image does not display, and the image source reference correctly, try convert your image to `x64base`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this directory `assets/www`

then place your html and image etc inside the `www` folder. 
And use the following code.

Cherry.java

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/htmltest.html");
```

htmltest.html

```
<img border="0" src="../res/drawable-hdpi/test.png" alt="nothing" width="304" height="228" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Now put your html and image etc inside the Assets folder. And use the following code.

Cherry.java

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.abtus_webView);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

htmltest.html

```
<img src="images/abc.png">
```

I have put the images into the images Folder in Assets folder. This is working for me correctly.

Comment: In my case image path in dynamic html is /images/abc.png. But it is not showing up. how to achieve that if / is prepended at the path. @Varma

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the image path

From:

`file:///android_drawable/test.png`

To:

`file:///android_res/drawable/test.png`

Answer (score 1):

If your images are small. Convert them to Base64 codings.

Explained here:
http://dean.edwards.name/my/base64-ie.html