# Html in textview: problems with frame layout scrolling and image viewing

Tags: android, textview

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/htmlText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFCC00" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If I set textview's text like this:

```
setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

scroll does not work.
Moreover, if in html there's an img tag, image is not viewed..why?

**edit:**

I switched to webview:

```
WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.newsView);
view.loadData(htmlString,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

and now I solved these problems, but I still got others:

1)How to set transparent background so I can see my app's one?

2)How to set foreground text color so, again, I can see my app's colors?

3)If there's an img tag image does not fit the view, leading to an horizontal scrolling. Text, instead, perfectly fills.

Comment: 1. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5003156/1321873
2. Set using HTML formatting
3. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3099344/1321873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display HTML content, use [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) supports only limited set of HTML tags - mainly for formatting text.

Comment: It works! There's still a little catch: I'd like to manually set background and text color, to adapt html to my app ui..is it possibile?

Comment: Another problem is about coding: in my html I often use "è","à","ì",... and, although setting coding to "iso 8859-1" it still does not display them

Comment: Can you please post your code? Update your question and add the code used to load the HTML in WebView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScrollView for the textView and it becomes scrollable. And then use

```
htmlText.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/htmlText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout >
```