# How to resize images in android webview according to different resolution?

Tags: android, android-webview, resolution, meta-tags, viewport

When i try to load the below html page in android browser, the image is not re-sizing according to resolution

```
<html>
<header>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/style.css"
        type="text/css">
</header>
<body>
    <p>This is a sample.</p>
    <br />
    <p>This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment This is a sample. this is a sample to test text alignment </p>
    <br />
    <img align="center" class="centeraligned"
        src="file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.sample.sample/sample.jpg"
        height="600" width="630" />
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

If i set viewport content width=600 images looks fine. but text aligns to left.
Am i missing any settings in viewport?

P.S: Text alignment issue occurs only in Kindle Fire HD and Kindle Fire Classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make the image fill the 100% width. So no matter what the device width height is. Something like below will do

```
<img src="file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.sample.sample/sample.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Else get the width, height dynamically and alter the image on run time

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Comment: i do have small images which is supposed not to occupy full width of the device.

Comment: What about some percentage then something like 50% or something

Comment: Setting width="50%" makes image to stretch, as height is still fixed

Comment: nope it won't be. just set only the width not the height, browser will auto adjust the height.

Comment: so u mean to say that don't set height?

Comment: yeap. Browser will auto adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

height="600" width="630"    you have set this constant pixels  ,so the image will never resize.
   you can added javascript ,to resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

For some purposes, [this below answer by Sheharyar Naseer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327010/383414) will help:

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```