# Android WebView One Column doesn't work with YouTube videos

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-websettings

I am loading RSS data from URL,and that RSS data can contain link to YouTube video.

Here is an example how link to youtube vide looks like:

```
div class="video-shortcode"><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="600" 
height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HXrcUyCVA6c"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

When I use this code, I get preview of YouTube video and I can play it, but images are to large as shown on the image below.
[image]

I used this  code for WebView:

```
WebView desc;

WebSettings ws = desc.getSettings();

ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
```

When I tried to use this code for WebView:

```
ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

It seems that YouTube videos dont work, because they are black, and I can't play them.

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Which android version are you using? And what are your android minSdk and targetSdk values?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />